# Node.js reading piped streams

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to read the contents of some `.gz` log files using streams in node.

I've started simply with: `fs.createReadStream('log.gz').pipe(zlib.createUnzip()`.

This works and I can pipe to `process.stdout` to verify.  I'd like to pipe to this a new writeableStream, that I can have a `data` event to actually work with the contents.  I guess I just don't fully understand how the streams work.  I tried just creating a new writable stream, `var writer = fs.createWriteStream()` but this doesn't work because it requires a path.

Any ideas how I can go about doing this (without creating any other files to write to)?

Comment: What is the purpose of write stream in your usecase?

Comment: Good question, so just realized I don't need it, I don't need the last pipe.  I was under the impression that I would need to pipe it somewhere else to get the events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var unzipStream = zlib.createUnzip()
unzipStream.on('data', myDataHandler).on('end', myEndHandler)
fs.createReadStream('log.gz').pipe(unzipStream)
```

That will get you the `data` and `end` events. Since it's log data you may also find [split](https://www.npmjs.com/package/split) useful to get events line by line.